# How to add two tables with different structure in a single worksheet in excel using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I want to write two tables with different structures in a single worksheet. One below the other. The fields in both tables are not same. Currently I am working around by writing data of both tables into two different worksheets in the same workbook.